# Remove Duplicate in an array and append values on same indexes php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove duplicates on basis of two keys i-e a and b in my case and need to append the values in the third key i-e c and resultant array should be like values at index a and b should be non repetitive and value on third index would be appended in new array. Example Arrays are given below: 
I have following array:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => 123
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 1
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 43134
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 4
        [c] => 5423
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 3
        [c] => 2342
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 123
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [a] => 1
        [b] => 0
        [c] => 43134
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 4
        [c] => 5423
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 3
        [c] => 2342
    )
```

)

and i want result like this:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 0
            [b] => 0
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123
                    [1] => 123
                )

```
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 1
        [b] => 0
        [c] => Array
            (
                [0] => 43134
                [1] => 43134
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 4
        [c] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5423
                [1] => 5423
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [a] => 0
        [b] => 3
        [c] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2342
                [1] => 2342
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, keeping track of elements already seen and append the 'c' element to the original array if you've already seen the element before (the a/b combo) - as a function - use `$flattened` directly if you don't want to stuff it into a function.

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    $a = $arr[$i]['a'];
    $b = $arr[$i]['b'];

    if (isset($result[$a][$b]))
    {
        // append the 'c' value
        $result[$a][$b]['c'][] = $arr[$i]['c'];
        // we've already seen the a/b combo
        continue;
    }

    // convert 'c' key to an array
    $arr[$i]['c'] = array($arr[$i]['c']);

    // keep the result
    $result[$a][$b] = $arr[$i];
}

$flattened = array();

// flatten the a/b structure to only keep the elements themselves
foreach ($result as $a => $b_level) {
    foreach ($b_level as $b => $element) {
        $flattened[] = $element;
    }
}

return $flattened;
```

Comment: value on 'c' index will never be the same

Comment: But the key will be the same, right? Your example shows that you're just repeating the same 'c' value .. do you mean to append the c values of all the following entries that already exist and not just repeat the element?

Comment: yeah... i want them to append... in example they are same but in real problem those are different.. and i want a and b index as well

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect that - it could be made simpler by keeping track through $a,$b as an array key or something like that, but this will work regardless of the values of $a and $b.